# Is it possible to add OpenLayers library to vue-cli 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, openlayers, vue-cli

I'm trying to implement Openlayers with vue-cli-3 but it seems that somehow I can't do it right, I'm missing something.

First, I installed vue cli

```
npm install @vue/cli -g
```

Then I added additional dependencies or to be more precise OpenLayers library.

```
npm install ol.
```

But I'm somehow failing in adding/registering dependencies in registering ol globally (in main.js file)

In my App.vue file when I import files like this it doesn't work. I'm getting this two errors

> [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "ReferenceError: ol is not defined"
>
> ReferenceError: ol is not defined

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

export default {

  data() {
    return {
      testing: 'SomeTests',
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      initMap();
    })
  }
}
function initMap() {
  var myMap = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2,
    })
  })
};
```

But when I include script and link tag in my index.html then code above works normally.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.2.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.2.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  <title>ol-basic</title>
</head>
```

My question is this. Is it possible to just import elements as it is recommended on [ol page](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html) with using modules and is it possible to somehow register ol package globally in my main.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after additional consultation I've finally figure it out.
Here it is working example, hope it helps someone.

```
// Import everything from ol
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';

function initMap() {
  new Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new XYZ({
          url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        })
      })
    ],
    view: new View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never importing `ol`, which is it is undefined, thereby giving you those errors. Try the following:

```
// Import everything from ol
import * as ol from 'ol';

// The OSM and TileLayer API is taken from the OpenLayers API.
function initMap() {
  var myMap = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2,
    })
  })
}
```

I tried it in a quick Vue project, and the function runs without any reference errors

Comment: Hmm, I ll try this at home. But if I understood correctly you could only import modules that you need as it is recommended on official site https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html

Comment: And of course, thank you for your effort and time :)

Comment: If you want to do it that way, you can import the modules you need too!
`import { Map, TileLayer, OSM, View } from 'ol'`